# linux: getting umask of an already running process?

Tags: linux, unix, umask

How can I check the umask of a program which is currently running?

[update: another process, not the current process.]

Comment: Of the current process? Or a foreign process?

Comment: There was a [patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/5/4/451) that went by for this a while ago, to report the process' umask in `/proc/pid/status` and `/proc/pid/stat`. But it doesn't seem to have gone into the mainline kernel.

Comment: Same question on [unix.se]: [Current umask of a process with pid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258284)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can attach gdb to a running process and then call umask in the debugger:

```
(gdb) attach <your pid>
...
(gdb) call umask(0)
[Switching to Thread -1217489200 (LWP 11037)]
$1 = 18 # this is the umask
(gdb) call umask(18) # reset umask
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

(note: 18 corresponds to a umask of `O22` in this example)

This suggests that there may be a really ugly way to get the umask using ptrace.

Comment: Thanks!  and bonus gratitude for the reminder to set the umask back!

Comment: If you're confused like I was - the line `$1 = 18` means that the process umask was previously 18 (022 in octal).

Comment: Better: call /o umask(027)

Comment: For followers, call/o outputs in octal like `022`

Answer (score 18):

Beginning with Linux kernel 4.7, the umask is available in `/proc/<pid>/status`.

Comment: In _your_ 3.10.0: maybe. In mainline 3.10.0: no.

Comment: It's in the kernel 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 of RHEL7.4.

Answer (score 9):

From the GNU C Library manual:

> Here is an example showing how to read the mask with `umask`
>   without changing it permanently:
>
> ```
> mode_t
> read_umask (void)
> {
>   mode_t mask = umask (0);
>   umask (mask);
>   return mask;
> }
> ```
>
> However, it is better to use `getumask` if you just want to read
>   the mask value, because it is reentrant (at least if you use the
>   GNU operating system).

`getumask` is glibc-specific, though. So if you value portability, then the non-reentrant solution is the only one there is.

Edit: I've just grepped for `->umask` all through the Linux source code. There is nowhere that will get you the umask of a different process. Also, there is no `getumask`; apparently that's a Hurd-only thing.

Comment: Yes, getumask is only on Hurd. The Linux man page has this helpful note: This function is documented in the glibc manual, but, as at glibc version 2.24, it is not implemented on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you're the current process, you can write a file to /tmp and check its setting.  A better solution is to call umask(3) passing zero - the function returns the setting prior to the call - and then reset it back by passing that value back into umask.

The umask for another process doesn't seem to be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague just showed me this command line pattern for this. I always have emacs running, so that's in the example below. The `perl` is my contribution:

```
sudo gdb --pid=$(pgrep emacs) --batch -ex 'call/o umask(0)' -ex 'call umask($1)' 2> /dev/null | perl -ne 'print("$1\n")if(/^\$1 = (\d+)$/)'
```

Answer (score 1):

At least with Kernel 4.18, there is an option to search the status proc file:
`grep Umask /proc/<PID>/status`