# Setting the umask of the jenkins process

Tags: linux, jenkins, file-permissions, umask

Our jenkins CI server (v1.499) runs tests that call URLs on the CI machine. The applications behind those URLs change the same temporary files as the unit test processes change, so those files need to be group writable. I fixed that for [apache already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/428416/282601), but totally fail with jenkins.

Modifying `/etc/default/jenkins` to include an `umask 002` command does not help. I'm [checking that with `gdb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/165718/282601) after restarting the service.

So how can I change jenkins' umask setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the umask by configuring the daemon, just add `--umask=002` to the daemon args in /etc/init.d/jenkins:

```
DAEMON_ARGS="--name=$NAME --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME --output=$JENKINS_LOG --pidfile=$PIDFILE --umask=002"
```

Comment: in meanwhile Jenkins was fixed - should work out of the box now without the above fix if Jenkins configuration has set up umask.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems on Ubuntu 12.04.5

It seems they have changed the standard umask from 022 to 027 for more security

https://www.mail-archive.com/jenkinsci-commits@googlegroups.com/msg30397.html

So I have switched it back in my setup by changing `/etc/default/jenkins` to have `UMASK=002`
That solved my problem, maybe you did set it wrong, or forgot to restart jenkins.

Check the umask of the running deamon

`ps ax | grep jenkins | grep umask`

Comment: I had to set the umask in /etc/init.d/functions. This was overriding the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins entry.

Answer (score 0):

If these tests run with Ant then you could try setting the umask in the `~/.antrc` file which gets invoked on Ant's startup.

Comment: they are a mix of ant and phing-based jobs.

Comment: In my case, I want the config.xml files to be group-writable.